# Is there a shorthand for conditional assigning in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-statements, assign

I have the following (simplified) code-fragment where I want to assign a value to variable $shell or $hole, depending on a certain condition ($ringIndex===1)

```
foreach($rings as $ringIndex=>$ring) {
    $polygon = $this->getPolygonFromRing($ring);
    if($ringIndex===1) {
        $shell = $polygon;
    } else {
        $hole = $polygon;
    }
    .... 
}
```

I don't want to use an extra variable ($polygon) if it is not necessary

I thought maybe something like this would work:

```
foreach($rings as $ringIndex=>$ring) {
    ($ringIndex===1?$shell:$hole) = $this>getPolygonFromRing($ring);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variable variable.

```
foreach($rings as $ringIndex=>$ring) {
    ${$ringIndex===1?'shell':'hole'} = $this->getPolygonFromRing($ring);
    .... 
}
```

However, I'll add my general advice: Any time you find yourself needing variable variables, you should almost always be using an array instead. If the variables are like `$foo1`, `$foo2`, etc. then it should be an indexed array, but in your case it should probably be an associative array with keys `shell` and `hole`.

Comment: And I thought mine was naughty.

Comment: I originally came up with yours, then realized it could be combined like this.

Comment: Brilliant (but potentially dangerous) shortcut and also great advice in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($rings as $ringIndex => $ring){
    $var = $ringIndex === 1 ? 'shell' : 'hole';
    $$var = $this->getPolygonFromRing($ring);
}
```